# How to specify custom onError sequence in Sequence Template in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I am trying to specify my custom error handling sequence in a Sequence Template. I tried adding it from the Design View and the Source View. But doesn't matter where I added it, that piece of code will be removed and doesn't get saved. So my Sequence Template always uses the default fault sequence.  Do you know how to specify a custom error handling sequence in a Sequence Template?

Thank you in advance.

onError="MyFailSeq" got removed automatically after deployed to the server.

```
<template name="MyTpltSeq" onError="MyFailSeq" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <sequence>
       ...
    </sequence>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have to do is to invoke a defined sequence. From there, I can specify my custom fault sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy or a sequence only be equipped with a fault handler using the attribute 'onError'. Please add the ‘onError’ attribute for sequence and try. Find more details [here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/10/wso2-esb-examples-best-practises-error-handling-wso2-esb/).

Comment: I had tried adding 'onError' attribute for sequence and that code got removed automatically.  What I have to do is to invoke a defined sequence. From there, I can specify my custom fault sequence.